# How can I have an anchor tag which targets its entire parent header tag?

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I have a number of websites which have lots of links where an anchor tag is inside a heading tag, e.g.:

```
<a href="#">
    <h2 style="padding-left: 50px;">
       A hyperlinked heading
    </h2>
</a>
```

This allows me to click anywhere in the h2 element, including any padding on the h2 element(!), and trigger the hyperlink.  However, it is not W3C compliant (checked with http://validator.w3.org/)

In order to be W3C compliant, I can't have any block tags (i.e. h2) inside inline tags (i.e. a).  So, the fix would be to place the anchor tags inside the heading tags:

```
<h2 style="padding-left: 50px;">
    <a href="#">
        A hyperlinked heading
    </a>
</h2>
```

The problem with that solution is that I can now only trigger the hyperlink by clicking the **text** inside the h2, but I actually want to be able to click **anywhere** on the h2 element.

I've found that I can add display:block to the anchor tags, like so:

```
<h2 style="padding-left: 50px;">
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">
        A hyperlinked heading
    </a>
</h2>​​​​​​​​​
```

This partly overcomes the problem in that it allows me to click most of the h2 element to trigger the hyperlink, but still does not allow me to trigger the hyperlink by clicking within any padded area of the h2.

A JSFiddle to highlight the problem can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/84rDG/

It has been suggested that I can remove all of the CSS from h2 elements and add it to an h2 class instead, and I can then apply the h2 class to any h2 tags **and** to any anchor tags which need the appearance of an h2 tag.  This isn't much good, though, because I'd have to replace most of my h2 tags with anchor tags and that would upset any SEO based on h2 elements.

It seems that HTML5 will allow anchor tags to surround heading tags, probably because a lot of people are trying to achieve what I've outlined here, but I need a solution that works in the meantime.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the padding from the `h2`-element and add it to the `a`-element

CSS:

```
h2.anchor {
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h2 > a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2 class="anchor">
    <a href="#">
        A hyperlinked heading
    </a>
</h2>​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that any h2 elements that are not hyperlinked (i.e. do not contain an a element) will no longer have padding.  Your solution would work if I could have padding on the a element if it is present, otherwise have padding on the h2 element.  I don't want to put the padding on both elements and have the padding double up on h2->a elements.

Comment: Edited my answer by adding a class to the `h2`-element

Comment: I would have liked my h2 elements to be uniform, without the need for the extra class, but it does work at least.  Cheers :-)

Comment: @SamWilliams If you can use margin instead of padding, you can add margin to both the h2 and the anchor - and it will collapse. Read on it.

Comment: If I've correctly understood what you're saying then this is a demo of it: http://jsfiddle.net/84rDG/3/.  The top heading there is the effect I'm trying to achieve and the bottom is what I've interpreted as your solution.  You can see that the clickable area is reduced, which isn't what I want, but collapsible margins are interesting all the same.  Thanks!